# Android Studio Flutter breakpoint is disabled when debugging

Tags: ios, flutter, android-studio, debugging

When starting debug of flutter app, and the breakpoint is red (enabled), once the app is installed, and the debug is starting, the breakpoint is disabled, and look like this:

[image]

How do I fix this so that the app will stop at breakpoint again.

I am using:

- Android Studio 2021.1.1 patch 2
- Flutter plugin 65.0.2
- Flutter version 1.22.4
- XCode 13.2.1

Comment: I am having the same issue now. I just updated the flutter plugin and flutter to 2.10.X from 2.8. Breakpoints are no longer working. I've wasted an hour with this...

Comment: @Sleewok what version of Android Studio and Xcode are you using?

Comment: Bumblebee 2021.1.1 patch 2 - I'm on Windows so it isn't related to xcode... I just tried clearing/invalidating caches.  I also did a flutter clean. Neither of those fixed it.

Comment: seem like it could be an issue with Bumblebee 2021.1.1 patch 2 @Sleewok thank you

Comment: I don't think it is related to this version of android studio. I have been running this version and didn't have any problems until I did the flutter plugin update and upgraded to flutter 2.10. The only thing I did differently was try to run my app in Edge browser (I hadn't tried that before).

Comment: What is your version of flutter plugin? @Sleewok

Comment: 65.0.2 @david72

Comment: ok then might be the flutter plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current flutter plugin 65.0.2 (for bumblebee 2021.1.1) has a bug "breaking" breakpoints in Android Studio. Downgrading to 64.1.2 gets breakpoints working again.

You can grab it here and install from disk (clicking on the gear when viewing plugins in android studio).
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter/versions/stable